# Optaplanner: manual grouping / group into multiple groups

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have the following dataset, and am trying to work out how to best write a specific constraint.

My `PlanningEntity` looks (roughly) as follows:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Participation {
    @PlanningId
    private long id;

    private Student student;
    private Lesson lesson;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "possibleEnrollments")
    private Boolean enrolled;
}
```

whereby a `Lesson` has a `public List<Subject> getSubjects()` (note: a list of multiple subjects).

What I would like to do in my `penalize` method is look at all participations of a student/subject (single subject!) combination. In other words, if I have lesson `A` with subject `1`, lesson `B` with subject `2` and lesson `C` with subjects `1` and `2`, I would like to do a grouping in such a way that in my penalize function I get two `(Student, List<Participation>)` callbacks: one for subject `1` and one for subject `2`, whereby the first lists contains lessons `A` and `C`, and the second list has lessons `B` and `C`. So, C is contained in two lists.

The following does not work:

```
constraintFactory
                .forEach(Participation.class)
                .groupBy(Participation::getStudent, Participation::getSubjects, toList())
```

since this groups on the entire `List` returned by `Participation::getSubject` and the set `1 and 2` attached to lesson `C` becomes a separate group.

I have currently 'solved' the problem as follows, with a custom `UniConstraintCollection`:

```
        return constraintFactory
                .forEach(Participation.class)
                .groupBy(Participation::getStudent, new UniConstraintCollector<Participation, Map<Subject, List<Participation>>, Map<Subject, List<Participation>>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Supplier<Map<Subject, List<Participation>>> supplier() {
                                return HashMap::new;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public BiFunction<Map<Subject, List<Participation>>, Participation, Runnable> accumulator() {
                                return (map, participation) -> {
                                    for(Subject s : participation.getSubjects()) {
                                        if(!map.containsKey(s)) {
                                            map.put(s, new ArrayList<>());
                                        }
                                        map.get(s).add(participation);
                                    }

                                    return () -> {
                                        for(Map.Entry<Subject, List<Participation>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
                                            entry.getValue().remove(participation);
                                        }
                                    };
                                };
                            }

                            @Override
                            public Function<Map<Subject, List<Participation>>, Map<Subject, List<Participation>>> finisher() {
                                return Function.identity();
                            }
                }).penalize(("name", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, (student, participationMap) -> {
                    ...
                });)
```

This works, in that I receive a map of `Subject` to `Participations` and allows me to calculate the penalty I want.

However, this means that I calculate one penalty value for all subject/list combinations 'together'. From a usability perspective, I would like to penalize each subject/list separately. Is there a way to do this? (Maybe by rewriting the `UniConstraintCollector` to provide multiple lists of `Participations`, instead of one single `Map<Subject, List<Participation>>`?)

P.S. Another approach I have tried to achieve the same goal is to work from the perspective of the `Subject`. So, making `Subject`s a ProblemFact on the PlanningSolution, and working with something like

```
        return constraintFactory
                .forEach(Subject.class)
                .join(constraintFactory.forEach(Participation.class),
                        JoinerSupport.getJoinerService().newBiJoiner(List::of, JoinerType.INTERSECTING, Participation::getSubjects)
                )
```

I assume this is the way I would need to go, using the JoinerType INTERSECTING, but this gives me an "Unsupported Joiner Type" exception in `AbstractLeftHandSide`.

Comment: Can you describe the motivation for this constraint? Not just the formal logic of it, but also why. I don't understand it well.

Comment: In this specific case, I am penalizing based on how many lessons of a specific subject a student is attending. However, data-technically, one lesson might be multiple subjects in one. So lesson A has subject ["X"], B has subject ["Y"], C has ["Y", "Z"]. A maximum of 1 lesson with subject "Y" is allowed for a specific student. So in my constraint, I would want to be able to see that the student is in fact attending two lessons in "Y" (lesson B ánd C), and penalize it accordingly

Comment: FYI `JoinerSupport` is not public API and you should not be using it. The `INTERSECTING` joiner is not implemented, hence the exception and why it is not included in the public API. If you stick to the public API, you should not be getting any unsupported joiners.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický I know :) My first hope was that (like JoinerType.EQUAL is accessed using Joiners.equal()) there would be a Joiners.contains(), but since that does not exist I started experimenting with JoinerSupport leading to the described error. But Joiners.filtering as described by Geoffrey solves my problem for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you start from Subject?

```
constraintFactory
    .forEach(Subject.class)
    .join(Participation.class,
        // Joiners.containedBy() would do this far more efficient
        filtering((s, p) -> p.getSubjects().contains(s))
    .groupBy((s, p) -> s, toList((s, p) -> p))
```

This could be an expensive constraint performance wise. Benchmark it.

Comment: Aha! That looks like what I was attempting to do with the `JoinerType.INTERSECTING` at the bottom of my question, but which is not supported. But if this works, that would be perfect... I will try this out and come back (tomorrow, probably)

Comment: This indeed solves my problem as expected! The total performance impact is manageable for now (I'm already filtering quite aggressively in other ways), but you are right it is indeed measurably slower. I would not oppose a `Joiners.containedBy` being introduced ;)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but it might solve your problem too. It's too long to add as a comment.

---

**The Boolean planning variable is typically an anti-pattern.**
If you improve your model, the constraint might become easier to implement.

[image]

Instead, you could model it like this:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Participation {
    @PlanningId long id;

    Student student;
    @PlanningVariable(...) Lesson lesson;
}
```

This simpler model (on the right) will solve far more efficiently. But in this case, how many `Participation` instances should you create?

- If the numbers of lessons for each student is fixed, that's obvious: that number per student.
- If the numbers of lessons for each student is a planning decision, use **overconstrainted planning**: `@PlanningVariable(nullable=true,...) Lesson lesson` and create one participation for the maximum number of lessons of each student. This will allow the solver to leave some participation instances unassigned.

See also the **Domain Modeling Guide** in the docs.

Comment: A valid point w.r.t. how my problem is currently modeled. However, I do not see how this could solve my question. Say I alter my model like you suggest. Then I have a list of Participation planning entities where the Lesson is the planned variable. Then in my constraint, I would still like to group my Participations by Student and (individual) subjects as described, but unless I'm missing something this problem is exactly the same in your proposed model.

Comment: I agree. I do think this is a better model, also for the natural moves, but it won't solve the problem in the question.